# Очень странно подгружается контент( slider slick) в аккордеоне Bootstrap, как это побороть?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

на странице [проекта](http://martynuk.esy.es/product.html) аккордеон, в одной из вкладок, а именно Цифровые технологии находится контент с кнопкой Подробнее, речь о первом блоке информации, изначально на нем должен быть виден определенный контент [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но его там нет [image: скрин1] 
при клике на кнопку Подробнее отображается скрытый контент (скрыт был свойством dysplay:none) в т.ч два слайдера slick, точнее будет сказано: они отображаются, но очень странно - [image: скрин2]появляются стрелки прокрутки слайдов, и при клике на них появляется сам слайдер,[image: скрин3] со вторым таже история. Они работают, все ок, но как только перегрузить страницу, возникает такая же проблема. Подскажите в чем может быть дело? Как это странное поведение побороть?

U.P.D.
Нарыл вот такое решение, но оно на все 100% не подходит, да и как его правильно применить к моей ситуации:
код кнопки Подробнее изменить на вот такую запись `<a href="#" class="btn-back" id="myBtn">Подробнее<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a>`
а слайдер записать

```js
$(document).on('click', '#myBtn', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $('div.hide-info1').toggle('normal', function(){

      // код слайдера

  });
  this.text = this.text == 'Свернуть' ? 'Подробнее' : 'Свернуть';
});
```

но это все равно не отрабатывает.

Comment: нашел схожую проблему где свойство display: none любому элементу блокирует появление слайдера, но почему, не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать инициализацию слайдера после того, как поле перестанет быть `display:none;`

Я как-то встречался с подобным, когда блок скрыт через `display:none` у JS есть проблемы с определением занимаемого им пространства. Потому как он реально не занимает никакого пространства на странице!
Сделать это можно навесив слушатель на событие появления слайдера, типа вот так:

```js
(function($) {
  $.each(['show', 'hide'], function(i, val) {
    var _org = $.fn[val];
    $.fn[val] = function() {
      this.trigger(val);
      _org.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
})(jQuery);


$('.mini-portfolio-thumb-slider').bind('show', function() {
  $(".mini-portfolio-thumb-slider").slick({
    parameters
  });
});
```

Для того, что-бы не отрабатывали все слайдеры, с классом `.mini-portfolio-thumb-slider` надо отловить параметр события и использовать его для дальнейшего нахождения слайдеров, принадлежащих именно этой области, которая появилась и вызвала событие.

```js
(function($) {
  $.each(['show', 'hide'], function(i, val) {
    var _org = $.fn[val];
    $.fn[val] = function() {
      this.trigger(val);
      _org.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  });
})(jQuery);


$('.mini-portfolio-thumb-slider').bind('show', function(e) {
  var showedBlock = $(e.target); // Эта переменная указывает на блок, который появился
  showedBlock.find('.mini-portfolio-thumb-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.mini-portfolio-item-slider',
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    infinite: false
  });

  showedBlock.find('.mini-portfolio-item-slider').on('init', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    var nrCurrentSlide = slick.currentSlide + 1,
      totalSlidesPerPage = nrCurrentSlide + 3;
    $('.controls').html(nrCurrentSlide + " - " + totalSlidesPerPage + " of " + slick.slideCount);
  }).slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    asNavFor: '.mini-portfolio-thumb-slider',
    infinite: false
  });

});
```

Попробуйте, может поможет.

Comment: Если так сделаете информации видно не будет, НО на странице будет большие белые поля!
Кроме того, не забывайте, что все там скрыто еще и в аккордеоне..

Comment: В принципе можно инициализировать слайдер и в событии onClick кнопки "Показать/Свернуть", но это раздует код, и как-бы не совсем что-ли изящно.

Comment: Ну вот есть ссылки 
`<a href="#" class="btn-back" onclick="$('div.hide-info1').toggle('normal'); this.text = this.text == 'Свернуть' ? 'Подробнее' : 'Свернуть'; return false">Свернуть</a>`

сразу после `$('div.hide-info1').toggle('normal');` можно добавить свою функцию типа `$('div.hide-info1').toggle('normal');$(".mini-portfolio-thumb-slider").slick({тут ваши параметры инициализации});` и так далее. Но этот вариант прост, но не удачен. Он будет инициализировать слайдер и при скрытии и при отображении.

Comment: ну тогда действительно не удачный

Comment: Вот поэтому код, который я привел в ответе наиболее оптимален. Он будет вызывать код внутри функции только на событие 'show' и именно элемента с классом mini-portfolio-thumb-slider.
Вам надо поменять код на ваш внутри функции:
`
$('.mini-portfolio-thumb-slider').bind('show', function() {
 // ЗДЕСЬ ВАШ КОД 
});
`

Comment: использовал ваш код, частично получилось, слайдер отобразился, но теперь вниз все 5 слайдов, хотя должен один показан.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36014/discussion-between-vladimir-jucov-and-zorro).